# VSTS - Cannot retrieve source tags because Build.SourceVersion is not set

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In VSTS, I am trying to build a Docker image. In my "Build an Image" step, when viewing the output logs, I see yellow text saying "Cannot retrieve source tags because Build.SourceVersion is not set". Perhaps this is because I've checked the "Include source tags" box. I added a bash step immediately after and tried to `echo $(Build.SourceVersion)` AND `echo $BUILD_SOURCEVERSION` which show up empty in the output log.

Based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/variables?tabs=batch, I should be able to use that pre-defined variable just fine.

[image]

It may be worth noting that I've connected to a "Remote repo" in the sources section, not "Github" (We're using Github Enterprise)

Am I missing something about this "Predefined variable"?

Answer (score 1):

The workaround is that you can get the tag through **Git command** (add Command line task to run bat, or PowerShell task), then set/create a variable (e.g. `tag` variable) through [Logging Commands](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md) (e.g. `echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=tag;]tagvalue"`), after that you can specify this tag in **Additional Image Tags** input box (`$(tag)`) of Docker task.

Comment: I like this strategy, but is there a way to do something similar except using bash? For example, is there a way for me to set a variable in `bash` then use it in another downstream environment?

Comment: @sg Which downstream environment? Do you mean environment in release? No, just can use in current environment. You can add the same task to the other environments to set variable.

Comment: Another build step. If I use that variable in a bash build step and add another bash step immediately after, I'm unable to use the variable again. I tried exporting it in the first bash step and it didn't persist into the second bash step.

Comment: @sg How do you use variable again? For `tag` variable, you need to access it by using `$TAG` code. You also can pass the variable in Arguments input box of Shell script task. For example, Arguments: `"$(tag)"`; Script: `echo "value: $1"`

Comment: I am doing this in powershell and I stored the latest git tag into a variable using `$tag = (git describe)` then I used performed my vsts operations from there